# Live Streaming IP Camera Stream to Youtube Using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

My Objective : To Transcode mjpeg stream from ip camera to youtube using ffmpeg

My Command :

```
ffmpeg -re -f mjpeg -i "http://192.168.0.101" -c copy -movflags +faststart  -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key>"
```

My Reference for above effort : [Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#HTTPLiveStreamingandStreamingwithmultiplebitrates)

But when i try to run the command, it seems something is being transcoded and transmitted but youtube live i am not able to see anything, below is the screenshot of command output

[image]

Comment: `-c copy` and -vcodec libx264` conflict with each other and `-movflags +faststart` only applies to mp4s, which you are not using. I recommend you take some time to know what these flags do.

Answer (score 5):

Last time I checked, Youtube requires an audio stream even if there is no input audio, so supply a dummy one.

```
ffmpeg -re -f mjpeg -i "http://192.168.0.101" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -g 60 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key>"
```

Comment: almost worked, but there is a resolution problem, even though the resolution of my IP Cam is set to 1024x768 , youtube says the resolution 600x800, any default settings of ffmpeg causing this ?

Comment: No, your input resolution is 800x600. See the properties for Input #0 in your image.

Comment: You were right, YouTube does require an audio stream. I removed the `-an` from my pipeline, to restore audio, and it started working properly.